# Inserting new records based on the date in pentaho

Tags: etl, pentaho, data-warehouse, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

i wanted to asks if this is possible in pentaho

I have a data looks like this yesterday 26/02/2021 , START_DATE TAKEN FROM SYSDATE

```
ID|CODE|NAME|MARKS|START_DATE|END_DATE
1|A01|KUMAR|90|26/02/2021|NULL
2|A02|RAJESH|80|26/02/2021|NULL
3|A03|SINGH|70|26/02/2021|NULL
```

So let's say that SINGH with CODE A03, he get a better marks(90) on 27/02/2021, so it will look like this

```
ID|CODE|NAME|MARKS|START_DATE|END_DATE
1|A01|KUMAR|90|26/02/2021|NULL
2|A02|RAJESH|80|26/02/2021|NULL
3|A03|SINGH|70|26/02/2021|27/02/2021
4|A03|SINGH|90|27/02/2021|NULL
```

As SINGH has different values in his MARKS, the old record of SINGH will meet it's END_DATE and SINGH new record with his latest MARKS will has START_DATE on the day the record being inserted and his END_DATE will still be a null.So the job will see if there are any differences in it's values, then if there are a some differences,it means the row has an 'updated' values, and the latest ones from the source that will be insert.
Can I implement this in pentaho?

[My Pentaho Jobs](https://filebin.net/5rwbu4t0gvdmhr44)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily using 'Update' and 'Insert/Update' step in only one transformation in Pentaho data integration.

[image]

You can see the sample from [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18hbhVWFdjIggsYMNYfOUdiBjKn3KTMIv?usp=sharing)

Comment: But what if the value that hasn't change? Like if SINGH still has MARKS 80,so it won't insert or update anything. If SINGH still has the same values from the sources, so there are no differences between the sources and the target, the record won't insert or update anything

Comment: Yes, those records will not insert. I already consider this step.

Comment: Btw Runa i've tried yours, and it will gave me an error since if i change the SINGH value, the new records ID inserting will be still SINGH old ID which is 3. It needed to be 4, how do i do that in the inserting step? When i delete the Update Fields in the Insert New Row step, i'm getting only null, and the end date also didn't get the today date.

Comment: In my transformation, i have insert ID from input records. So, if ID=3 in the new record then 3 will be insert for SINGH, if ID=4 then 4 will be insert. Its fully depend on your records. If you want auto increment ID in your database table then you can easily set ID column as auto increment in any database. And in this case remove ID from 'Insert New Row' step as this will automatically handle by your DB.

Comment: Okay so it depends on the table structure, and i tried using get system info in my job (i've provided the link above), the system info i tried to get the system date for the new end_date value, and it didn't work, maybe you know why?

Comment: :) You need to use 'Get system date' step after input the data. I have updated your transformation and uploaded a new transformation on your location. Please check.

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHARM :D Thankyou somuch, sorry if it was "dumb" questions and another "dumb" problems.. I'm still learning with pentaho , Thankyou somuch ,you're a lifesaver :)

Comment: You're most welcome. Any help just post a new question. I am available here .